# Can the mentioned verb be in a bare infinitive form?

Tags: verbs, gerund-vs-infinitive, ing, bare-infinitive

> However, rather than **undermine** its epistemic value, the intentional
>   character of testimony is arguably essential to this value.

Shouldn't it be "undermining" or "undermine"? As it is after "than", I believe the verb should be either an -ing form or a to-be form. Or, can it be a bare infinitive as well?

Comment: The "rather than" construction freely takes bare infinitival and gerund-participial clauses as complement, so both your examples are fine. The expression "rather than undermine its epistemic value" is an adjunct with the adverb "rather" as head.

Comment: @BillJ Is to-be form acceptable as well?

Comment: Yes, but it would not be natural.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct using both "undermine" and "undermining" since both create valid valid verb phrases that serve as objects of the preposition, rather than.  I believe "to undermine" would be correct as well, but it sounds "too wordy" when using undermine in this form is also considered an infinitive.